# How to remove an item from a list in python with substring match

Tags: python-2.7

I have got a list l1 = ['00001MMYYYSSSS', '00002YYSSMMYNNN', '00003FFMMNNNSS'] and another list 
l2 = ['00001', '00003']. I need to remove the items at index 0 and 2 in the list l1 as it contains the string given in l2. How do I go about doing this?

I have tried the solutions mentioned [here][Is there a simple way to delete a list element by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793324/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-a-list-element-by-value) and 
[here][Python: subset elements in one list based on substring in another list, retain only one element per substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302915/python-subset-elements-in-one-list-based-on-substring-in-another-list-retain-o) but they return an empty list. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
l1 = ['00001MMYYYSSSS', '00002YYSSMMYNNN', '00003FFMMNNNSS']

l2 = ['00001', '00003']

l_result = [x for x in l1 if not any(l in x for l in l2)]  # ['00002YYSSMMYNNN']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Hello World program i

l1 = ['00001MMYYYSSSS', '00002YYSSMMYNNN', '00003FFMMNNNSS'] 
l2 = ['00001', '00003']
L3=[]

for el in l2:

  for el1 in l1:
    if el in el1:
     L3.append(el1)
for l3 in L3:
    l1.remove(l3)
print l1
```

Comment: I tried it but print l3, prints out an empty list. In fact l3.append(el1) is marked as unreachable code.

Comment: Try this one, I test ed it